# How to kill chickens in a Chicken Generator?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

So I've just built a Chicken Generator, that should supply me with raw chicken meat, in order to sell in to Butchers.

However, I've encountered an issue: I used a Weighted Presssure Plate to activate the kill mechanism when there are enough chicken. The problem: chicken are less than one block tall, which makes suffocating them impossible, unless the Pressure Plate is destroyed (which I don't want to happen).

So, what cost-effective kill mechanism (that doesn't cost me hundreds of Redstone) should I use, eventually replacing the Pressure Plate with something else?

Please note that:

- Fire or Lava aren't options, since I want **Raw** Chicken.
- I'm playing Minecraft 1.8.7 and want an answer that works for this version, prefferably.

Comment: Are you able to use commandblocks/scoreboards? They are kinda "cheating", not suitable for survival game, but you did not mentioned if you are (or not) okay with solutions with them.

Comment: Well, if I mentioned selling them to Butchers, I'm not okay with them. I could have simply used commands to give me the Emeralds directly. @AntoineHejlík

Comment: You could put dispensers on ground level next to the pressure plate to fill them with arrows. So long as you have a good supply of flint and/or skeletons to kill you should have plenty of arrows since your machine will supply ample feathers.

Comment: Not a very bad idea, it should be taken into consideration. Anyway, I found a way to do this after a couple of attempts. @santyclause

Comment: @John, if you've found a good way to do this, please document it in an answer to assist future users.

Answer (score 1):

If you are playing on version **1.11+**, you can use gamerule `maxEntityCramming`.
[This gamerule](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#gamerule) does that when number >0 given, when there are more mobs (respectively "pushable entities") on one block than the number+1, they will get 3 damage.

> The maximum number of other pushable entities a mob or player can push, before taking 3 (Heart.svgHalf Heart.svg) suffocation damage per half-second. Setting to 0 disables the rule. Damage affects survival-mode or adventure-mode players, and all mobs but bats. Pushable entities include non-spectator-mode players, any mob except bats, as well as boats and minecarts.

So all you need to do is to collect chickens on one block - typically directly above hopper. Then you just need to wait until there will be more than X+1 of them, then they will kill themself automatically. No redstone needed except hopper for collecting the stuff.

If you are in pure survival or don't have access to gamerules, **the default value is 24**, unless changed by server admins.

Be aware that a lot of mobs on one spot produces A LOT of server-lag! (That is the purpose to kill them if they are on one spot in huge numbers, however reasonable limit is not 24, but something like 5-10 only)

Comment: I should have mentioned that I play on versions prior to 1.11... But still, good answer, +1.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this[image]

[image]

this works in minecraft 1.10.

as well you get raw chicken.

explanation:

Use the magma block below the pressure plate.

when the chicken stands on the magma block it gets hurt, also it triggers the pressure plate, for redstone signal.

when the chicken dies, it drops raw meat.

now collect the drops using minecart with hopper just under the magma block

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your answer more? How it works? How to build this?